# How to create a iOS-like settings page?

Tags: ios, uitableview, application-settings

I want to make something like this for my app:

[image]

I tried using UITableView with static cells but I cannot get the grey blocks to separate into different groups of setting options (like the image above)

How can I add the grey blocks?

Comment: It's a grouped style table view.

Comment: Sorry...I'm kinda new to swift...what does that mean and how can I do it? Thanks! :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place for those kind of question; have a look at the apple docs or use a search engine for beginner iOS development

Comment: I didn't say I was a beginner...I'm new to it. There's a difference; I have put together a pretty good app based off little help. I'm just asking how to add a "feature"

Comment: Read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is set the table view's style to `UITableViewStyle.Grouped`. This may not get you dividers of the correct height, though. To do that, you need to implement `tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` and return a `UIView` of the appropriate height and color. You could also do it as a footer. Works either way.

I'm not going to write out all of the code and do screen shots of where to set this stuff in the Storyboard. I wish I had that kind of time, but I don't. :) This, along with the right documentation--the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS" as suggested by @rmaddy--should get you where you want to go.